# OS X base system is locked, unable to install Sierra on Mac

Tags: macos, disk-utility, install, recovery, disk-format

I made a boneheaded mistake while erasing my hard drive (can’t tell you what that mistake was) and now I can’t reinstall macOS! Can someone tell me what I need to do so I can free up the hard drive and correctly reinstall the new copy of macOS?

I’d appreciate any advice and guidance. I’ve posted the pictures to provide details.

[image][image][image]

Comment: An added note is that I can not select the erase button in disk Utility. It is grayed out along with the restore and unmount selections. The memory on APPLE HDD, which is the SATA internal physical Disk is completely taken up by OS X Base system.  I’d like to know how can I reinstall macOS, in this case? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

1. Boot to Internet Recovery Mode (<kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>)
2. Open Disk Utility and erase your internal disk
3. Install macOS ([the macOS that came with your Mac, or the version closest to it that is still available will be installed](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)).
4. After rebooting and configuring your system download and install macOS Sierra.

Comment: I appreciate your response however I cannot select erase. It won’t allow me to... “erase” is grayed out. What can I do to free up the memory?

Comment: Perhaps I  misunderstood the steps that you suggested. The iMac automatically loads up to internet recovery mode. I think I saw a previous posting when you helped someone with this sort of problem. But I’m not sure what to do in Terminal to restore memory.

Comment: @AmberKhan If disk0s2 with 1.9 billion 512-blocks is mounted to / (screenshot2-line3), you aren't booting to Internet Recovery Mode.

Comment: ok i see...I erase Apple HDD correct?? And not the OS X Base system? This might be a silly question but it looks like I have two internal hard drives. Thank you

Comment: Booted to Internet Recovery Mode you will have two OS X Base systems: one (~1 TB) falsely installed/moved? to your internal disk and the second proper one "d/led"  from Apple (~2 GB). You have to erase the internal disk.

Comment: oh my gosh thank you! It’s installing now. Perfect instructions.  Problem solved.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but I don't understand what klanomath is suggesting. I am not really a Mac person. Would you please tell me how you solved this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: @Robert If you are booting to the internal main volume (disk0s2 is mounted to /) AND its name is "OS X Base system" AND only ~1.2 GB of this volume (with 120 GB or more) is used then some error occurred earlier and a basic recovery system was installed to disk0s2. To resolve this problem you have to boot to another boot volume, erase your internal disk and install a new system or restore a backup.

Comment: @robert Easiest solution if you don't have bootable Mac OS external media is to make some. Either using another Mac to make a bootable install USB, or plug an external HDD (not flash drive) into your Mac and install Mac OS on the external disk from recovery mode. Then Option-boot from the external disk into Mac OS. It'll run slow, but you'll be able to download the Mac OS installer from the App Store and use it to install to the internal HD while running off the external one.

Comment: @robert Or just go to the Genius Bar, if that's an option. I'm loathe to suggest something other than specifically how to fix it yourself, but if you don't have the requisite items (external HD, etc) then it's a potential solution. Back during my tenure we would reload OS X for anyone while they waited, though I don't know if they do things differently now. Been a decade.